# Force http:// to https:// in a sails.js App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl, sails.js

I try to force my Sails.js WebApp which is hosted on heroku(no nginx installed) from http:// to https:// and use this [express middleware](https://github.com/thenativeweb/forcedomain) in my sail.js app:

In Express it would look like this:

```
app.use(forceDomain({
  hostname: 'www.example.com',
  port: 4000,
  protocol: 'https'
}));
```

I tried to use it in my config/http.js file in my sails.js app:

```
middleware: {

        forceDomain: function (req, res, next) {
            forceDomain({
                hostname: 'www.myurl.com',
                port: 4000,
                protocol: 'https'
            });
            next();
        },

        order: [
            'forceDomain',
          ...
}
```

I don't understand exactly how to use this "app.use()" thing in sails.js. 
It is [here explained](https://imfly.gitbooks.io/sailsjs-docs-gitbook/content/en/concepts/Middleware/Middleware.html), but I didn't really understand. What I now have doesn't work(no errors, but also no redirecting). How can I fix this?

Installed [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-httpsredirect) - doesn't work either.

Comment: I think it should be forceDomain: forceDomain({hostname...etc}),

Comment: No that doesn't make sense at all. hmm

Comment: If you're using nginx (as reverse proxy) you can do it there.

Comment: I don't use ngingx

Comment: I used the same @PomeGranate approach but I wrapped it within a custom policy in order to keep the code clean and modular and in order to implement the redirect only on selected methods. The drowback is that you have to manage it on all your methods inside the policy configuration also if you want to use https across all your application api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution how to force ssl on a sails.js app running on heroku without nginx and without external modules:

In the config/http.js file there is an example of custom middleware:

```
****************************************************************************
*      Example custom middleware; logs each request to the console.        *  
****************************************************************************

myRequestLogger: function (req, res, next) {
        console.log("Requested :: ", req.method, req.url);
        next();
 }
```

I made my own custom middleware function which controls if the request is secure, and if not, it redirects the request to https:// or if its a websocket request it redirects the request to wss://

```
 order: [
         ...
         'forceSSL',
          ...
         ],


forceSSL: function (req, res, next) {

            if (req.isSocket) {
                return res.redirect('wss://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
            } else if (req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] == "http") {
                return res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
            } else {
                next(); //it's already secure
            }
}
```

No need for extern modules or hookups. just that function and it works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, did you have to do anything special to get the websocket to work? i'm also running sails.js (in docker) without nginx on aws using their application load balancer and getting "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502". with 1 instance websocket works fine, but once I add 2 or more instances I start getting disconnected...

Answer (score 2):

Every value in the `sails.config.http.middleware` dictionary (besides `order`) should be an Express-style middleware function -- that is, a function that accepts `req`, `res`, and `next`, which is exactly what the `forcedomain` module returns.  The issue in your code is that you're wrapping that function in another function instead of just returning it.  Try:

```
middleware: {

    forceDomain: forceDomain({
      hostname: 'www.myurl.com',
      port: 4000,
      protocol: 'https'
    }), // <-- the call to `forceDomain()` returns a configured Express middleware fn.

    order: [
      'forceDomain',
      ...
}
```

This assumes that you have `var forceDomain = require('forcedomain')` at the top of that file!

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Seems to be correct, but doesn't work in my app. I have no errors, but the redirect doesn't happen. So how to solve this redirect thing in sails.js??

Comment: I didn't write the `forcedomain` module and can't really vouch for it doing what it claims to do, but if it was going to work, that's how you'd do it!

Comment: true, your solution looked correct. thanks :) I solved it without the module.